# ¿Como cambiar la carpeta en la que abre Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter

Hola estoy tratando cambiar la carpeta en que abre el Jupyter, pues cuando lo inicio, empieza en el "C:\Users\USUARIO" y quiero que abra "C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\Programas Jupyter". Estuve leyendo stackoverflow en ingles y el faq de jupyter pero nada...

Comment: Bienvenido @Nico a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que tienes 2 formas de hacer esto, la primera seria:
Desde una consola de comandos de windows ir a la ruta que quieres que sea tu directorio base y después ejecutando jupyter notebook

```
cd "C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\Programas Jupyter"
jupyter notebook
```

La segunda manera que se me ocurre es que localizes el ejecutable de jupyter notebook en tu sistema, puedes encontrarlo usando la funcionalidad de windows para "encontrar programas y archivos" por ejemplo si estas en windows 7 o tecleando el nombre del programa directamente si estas en el escritorio de windows 10.

Una vez que veas el icono del programa para ejecutarlo, pulsa boton derecho "abrir ubicación del archivo" y esto te llevara en el explorador de windows al lugar donde esta el ejecutable del programa.

Ahora si das botón derecho propiedades sobre este ejecutable podras editar estas propiedades y en el campo que indica "Start in:" puedes poner la ruta "C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\Programas Jupyter".

Answer (score 0):

Solo abre el cmd y escribe

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

y luego jupyter notebook

--notebook-dir="D:\Directorio

Comment: Para futuras participaciones por favor evita los textos groseros o agresivos